# Открыть пункт меню в новом окне на PHP

Tags: javascript, html

Ссылки меню открываются в новой ВКЛАДКЕ. Есть задача открывать их в новом ОКНЕ. Уже пробовал:

1. target_top - открывает опять в новой вкладке;
2. `<A HREF='#nul' ONCLICK='window.open("http://www...` - не отображается в меню вообще.

Думаю, всё предельно понятно, а вот и сам код:

```
<li><a href='https://www.бла-бла' target='_blank'>Пункт</a></li>

      <li><a href='https://www.бла-бла' target='_blank'>Пункт2</a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.бла-бла' target='_blank'>Пункт3</a>
<ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='https://www.бла-бла' target='_blank'>Пункт4</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.бла-бла' target='_blank'>Пункт5</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

Думаю, что загвоздка может быть ещё в том, что всё это лежит внутри вот этого:

Вношу правки в вопрос, конкретизируя, что нужно. 
Есть код, открывающийся в новой ВКЛАДКЕ:
<li><a href='https://www.nostalgie.be/radioplayer&#39; target='_blank'>Эфир</a></li>
Его просто нужно открыть в новом ОКНЕ, как у меня на этом же сайте:
http://www.nostalgie.be/radioplayer ','','Toolbar=1,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0,Width=550,Height=800');'>Эфир
Мне кажется, решение должно быть несложным. Спасибо.

Comment: Это не на php делается. Пример из гугла: `<a id="Lnk" href="http://javascript.ru/window-open" >Клик</a>
<script>
var link = document.getElementById('Lnk')
link.setAttribute("onclick","popupWin = window.open(this.href,'contacts','location,width=490,height=368,top=0'); popupWin.focus(); return false")
</script>`

Comment: Эдуард, я делал вот что:<A HREF='#nul' ONCLICK='window.open(&apos;http://www.nostalgie.be/radioplayer &apos;,&apos;&apos;,&apos;Toolbar=1,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0,Width=550,Height=800&apos;);'>Эфир</A>  - тогда пункт меню не отображается вообще. А у Вас начало с <A, после чего закрывающий скрипт. Неполный код.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы не играться с кавычками можно передавать `this.href` в качестве первого аргумента для `window.open`

```
<a href="https://google.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href,'','width=auto'); return false">Google</a>
```

Третий аргумент для `window.open` важен, по крайней мере, для браузера `FireFox`. Иначе ссылка откроется просто в новой вкладке.

После `window.open` возвращаем (`return`) `false`, для предотвращения действия по умолчанию.

Дополнительная информация по [window.open](https://javascript.ru/window-open) и [действиям браузера по умолчанию](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action)

Comment: Только что вставил Ваш код в меню. И указанный пункт не отображается в меню. Не в том ли проблема, что перед кодом вот что:  <div class='container'>
   <b:section id='navigation-wrapper' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='HTML11' locked='false' title='top navigation' type='HTML' version='1'>
  <b:widget-settings>
    <b:widget-setting name='content'>